# Javascript Call Function with String

Tags: javascript

I'm sending callback strings from php to javascript.

```
var PostType = function () {
    return {
        create: function(form, response) {
            Custom.resetForm(form);
            $('#create-form').modal('hide');
            Grid.reset();
        }
    };

}();
```

I have to call PostType.create method but it's  not working.

I'm calling it like:

```
//Call function
callFunction: function(func, form, response) {
    var fn = window[func];

    if(typeof fn === 'function') {
        fn(form, response);
    } else {
        console.log(typeof fn);
        return false;
    }
}

// Call
Custom.callFunction(response.callback, $form, response);
```

What should i do?

Comment: You cannot call it with `callFunction`. Why do you need this?

Comment: Why i can't Sure i can but how? Normal function calls is working.

Comment: Because `callFunction` is not a normal function call? You cannot even *reference* the `PostType.create` method. Just call it normally! Why would you need `callFunction`?

Comment: callFunction is my method to call javascript functions with string. I can not reach to the object.method with string. Ther must be another way to do this.

Comment: If you need a dedicated function that calls other functions with strings, you're doing something seriously wrong, and need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i know what i'm doing. I'm asking a simple question here. I'm not arguing. I wonder, somebody will help me here?

Comment: Yes, you cannot reach it. So what is your question? "What should I do" is not valid. We don't even know what you *want* to do. So again: **Why do you need/have/use this `callFunction`?**

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. I can reach a javascript function  with a string. Sample: make a request to a php file with jquery $.ajax function, and get response in $.ajax's success function. Php returns a json object and you get that json string and parse right? So; php returns an array like this: json_encode(array("status" => true, "callback" => "doThisJs")). Javascript gets that string as a json object, and you can call any function that named "doThisJs" with my callFunction method! I do not know how can i be more clear...

Comment: Just use JSONP, which will do `doThisJs({status:true})` - and it will be evaled automatically. Also, why does only your PHP script know which function to call? Shouldn't you just pass the expected function as a success callback?

Comment: @Bergi, ok i'm gonna start from beginning. Let's tell there is a content form that sends data to db. Form uses javascript ajax method to send info to php. Php gets the form data ($_POST) via xmlhttp (ajax) and saves to the db. After finishes saving, returns a  json_response. Javascript $.ajax when gets the json response, in the success method, checks for response if a callback variable available for call. So php tells to frontend to i did my job, so you have to call this callback! I really do not know how could not you get this...

Comment: Well, I'm getting it now, and I'm telling you that you don't need to send function names from PHP to JS. Just pass `PostType.create` as a callback function to `$.ajax`

Comment: I would if i had $.ajax method for each form. I have a method that catches form requests while submit and do it with $.ajax to prevent refreshing page. So this method checks for a callback in beforeSend and success sections. This is why i need it to call a callback from string. It would be a code crowd if i write request functions to each form...

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the complete request function, you just would need to pass different callback functions to it. Instead of checking in the PHP code which form was submitted, do it in the JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it.

When calling object > method with window;

```
window["object"]["method"];
```

So i'v modified my callFunction to this:

```
callFunction: function(func, form, response) {
    //Check for func string if contains any "." (dot)
    if(func.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        // If so; split "." character to get Object name and the method name
        func = func.split(".");

        var fn = window[func[0]][func[1]];
    } else {
        var fn = window[func];
    }

    if(typeof fn === 'function') {
        fn(form, response);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
```